# Asterisks in Java Path

Tags: java, path, glob

I am going through the OCA/OCP Java SE & Programmer I & II Study Guide. On page 520 there is a method to use for matching:

```
public void matches(Path path, String glob){
    PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
}
```

Now, on the next page there is a piece of code that makes use of this method:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Path path1= Paths.get("0*b/test/1");
    Path path2 = Paths.get("9\\*b/test/1");
    Path path3 = Paths.get("01b/test/1");
    Path path4 = Paths.get("0*b/1");
    String glob = "glob:[0-9]\\*{A*,b}/**/1";
    matches(path1,glob);
    matches(path2,glob);
    matches(path3,glob);
    matches(path4,glob);
}
```

According to the book the result should be:
true
false
false
false

However, when I attempt to run it I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 1:       0*b/test/1
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at pathmatcherobjective.PathMatcherObjective.main(PathMatcherObjective.java:63)
    Java Result: 1
```

My question is: Have I missed something in the set up? Do I need to have something specific enabled in order to run this? Or is the book just wrong? I am only studying for the Java Professional exam so I'm not sure on everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows operating system the character `*` is not allowed for valid file and directory names. So do the characters listed on the [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> You can use any character in the current code page for a name,
>   including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character
>   set (128–255), except for the following reserved characters:
>
> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>     are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>     Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

For UNIX see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations). 
On POSIX allowed characters include `A–Z a–z 0–9 . _ -`, reserved are `/ null`.

Probably the examples where run on the OS where `*` is allowed.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely explains it. I was completely lost here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which character failed your code (apart from those explained in the previous answer), you can read the method normalize in the OpenJDK source code: [WindowsPathParser](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPathParser.java#l163)

- Java forbids use of char before < 32 (ASCII)
- Java forbids use of char in this list: <>:\"|?*
- **Java forbids Path component to end with a space.**

The last one is a tricky one: when you use Explorer, it will trim the space at end of file entry but some C/C++ Windows API (or even C `fopen`) allows to create path with space at their end.

The result is a file/directory you can't rename/delete from the Explorer (because it trims the file name).

Beside, because the previous Answer quotes MSDN:

> Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1
>   through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>   are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams

The normalize method (called by `Paths.get` as shown in the stacktrace) does not allows the use of ':' to specify a stream (see [Using Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).